# how to binding object-c control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I would like to binding this object-control, but it is the first time and I have some problem
can you help me?
I have no problems with the properties and voids "simple" but the other I do not know how to do
thanks 
Cris

this is a .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, KGModalBackgroundDisplayStyle){
    KGModalBackgroundDisplayStyleGradient,
    KGModalBackgroundDisplayStyleSolid
};

@interface KGModal : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) BOOL tapOutsideToDismiss;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *modalBackgroundColor;

@property (nonatomic) KGModalBackgroundDisplayStyle backgroundDisplayStyle;


+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

- (void)showWithContentView:(UIView *)contentView;

- (void)showWithContentView:(UIView *)contentView andAnimated:(BOOL)animated;

- (void)showWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentViewController;

- (void)showWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentViewController andAnimated:(BOOL)animated;


- (void)hideWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)())completion;

- (void)hideAnimated:(BOOL)animated withCompletionBlock:(void(^)())completion;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to make bindings:

- Manual writing bindings. Read [Xamarin's docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries) about it;
- Using `Objective Sharpie` for [automatically binding generation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries/objective_sharpie).

Code looks relatively simple, so probably you could use `Objective Sharpie` generated binding without additional patching it.